# Trying to save a Flash video in my cache - where do temporary Flash files get stored with Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser, flash

I am watching a video lecture which seems to be in Adobe Flash and I want to save it. I'm using Firefox to [view this website](http://cs75.tv/2009/fall/).

My `about:cache` result is below, if that helps.

```
Memory cache device

Number of entries: 212  
Maximum storage size: 13312 KiB  
Storage in use: 8087 KiB  
Inactive storage: 6819 KiB

List Cache Entries Disk cache device

Number of entries: 3224  
Maximum storage size: 500000 KiB  
Storage in use: 26066 KiB  
Cache Directory: C:\Documents and Settings\nvarm\Local Settings\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\d74svniy.default\Cache

List Cache Entries Offline cache device

Number of entries: 0  
Maximum storage size: 512000 KiB  
Storage in use: 0 KiB  
Cache Directory: C:\Documents and Settings\nvarm\Local Settings\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\d74svniy.default\OfflineCache

List Cache Entries
```

Comment: If all you want to do is save the video files, then it's pretty straight forward. All you have to do is click the download button right on the page. Did you not see that? Or was it not available when you originally posted this question?

Answer (score 2):

NirSoft has a video cache viewing program at [video cache view](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/video_cache_view.html). He also has other programs to see the web caches and other interesting information like BHO's and the like. All his utilities are free.

Comment: this program is wonderful, it can get a little slow when scanning if you use multiple browsers and never clear your caches, but it's great for grabbing videos, even those pesky "temp" ones.

Answer (score 0):

Flash (flv) videos are stored in "Disk cache device". The path for the cache files is:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<User>\Local Settings\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<Profile>.default\Cache
```

Click on "List Cache Entries" on about:cache page. Then search for your file with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>F</kbd> (for example, you can type in cs75.tv or .flv). Click on the related key and a new page opens. Look at the "file on disk" info and it should tell you in which subfolder your flv file is located inside Cache folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Firefox, check out [this method](http://www.walkernews.net/2007/06/03/where-is-firefox-internet-files-cache-folder/). No downloading or installing third-party plugins/apps involved. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [flashgot](http://flashgot.net/) addon and save yourself the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firefox, I consider it would be easier to use [the Download Flash and Video plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/53003/) for your task.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [site](http://cs75.tv/2009/fall/) and expand e.g. the section "Lecture 0 HTML" and then "Video". Now you can click one of the two links - "download" or "torrent" - with your left mouse button, where it says "Flash". For a torrent download you will need a [BitTorrent client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_BitTorrent_clients) software, such as [µTorrent](http://www.utorrent.com/).

[image: a]

Unless you have changed this behavior, by default, Firefox should prompt you to either save or open the Flash file on your computer. See the screenshot below.

[image: b]

If you don't get this prompt, you can right click on the link and then click "Save Link As". See screenshot below.

[image: c]

Answer (score 0):

On the left top corner there should be an orange fire fox tab. Click that and save the page. Go to the folder you saved it to and the flash should be somewhere in there.

Comment: It would work if the video in question wasn't streamed. In this case, the video is streamed and as such the video file isn't saved alongside with the page itself.

Comment: I'd also add the latest versions of firefox don't have the orange tab any more - they've switched to a more chromic theme.

Comment: There's always IDM (internet download manager) to make things easier although it won't work on youtube videos and it's not free except for trials.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I don't currently have firefox anymore but I think the option to save page still exist though.